# Form not submitting with single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form where I bound action with validation. Following is line of form which calls `JavaScript` check.

```
<form id="signup_form" method="post" action="javascript:check();">
```

I have following `JavaScript`:

```
function check(form){
   flag = 0
   doValidations();
  if(flag==1){
     return;
  } else {
     $('#signup_form').submit();
     $('#signup_form').attr('action', 'NewSignupConfirm.php');
     return false;
  } 
}
```

When I click on `submit`, it does all validation and even show message of else statement but do not submit form. Than I again click on submit button and it submits form. What is wrong with it? any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id="signup_form" method="post" action="NewSignupConfirm.php" onsubmit="return check();">


function check(form){
   flag = 0
   doValidations();
  if(flag==1){
     return false;
  } else {
     return true;
  } 
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: After submitting answer I realize this and have completed but your answer is correct and excellent. Thank you Deepak

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code

```
function check(form){
  if(doValidations()){
     return true;
  } else  {
     return false;
  } 
}
```

You don't need to add flag variable just return true or false from doValidations method